# How to always output update's and delete's SQL

Tags: c#, linqpad

I don't want to hardcode sql strings in C#. I use LINQ to do this the following way:

I write in LINQ (in LINQPad) the query and then I run it. There's this "SQL" tab that outputs what I've run to SQL, and uses declared variables. This is good for me because I can parse this SQL output and generate a C# stub that opens an `SQLConnection` and `SQLCommand` with `try/catch`, and I can add parameters to the command.

The problem is that LINQPad only converts it to SQL sometimes. If it's an `update` or `delete`, sql is only output is those actions affected anything in the db.

Is there any way to output updates and deletes anyways, or at least preview them without running?

Comment: Question: why don't you just use LINQ in your application?

Comment: That's a step forward we plan taking in the future, but not exactly now. I need a workaround until then.

Comment: It'll take like 15mins to set up a LINQ-to-SQL mapping for your database... it's a serious drain of your time _not_ to!

Comment: I think so, but my boss wants me to focus on some other stuff first.

Comment: It's like your boss wanting you to lay the tracks for a train line through a mountain without digging the tunnel first :P

Comment: You say ` If it's an update or delete, sql is only output is those actions affected anything in the db` - but what **other** kind of updates or deletes are there?

Comment: An update/delete does or does not affect the db. That depends if the `WHERE` matches anything. I get what you mean though; if it's an update, by definition it means that it affects the db. Otherwise, it wouldn't be an update.